# How to find the official international country code for localization with iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, localization

I want to localize my app , and I didn't find that the official international code for it. and I found the Korean is ko, is it right? and what are other codes? and the English is en-GB, is it right ? what means about GB, and when I localize my app , I add the en.lporj or en-GB.lproj? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Correct, Korean is "ko". [Full list of language codes](http://applingua.com/devzone/2011/06/using-the-correct-language-codes-en-ja-fr-de-etc/). You may be able to append a country code to the language code for resources that are specific to a country. Such as "en_GB" or "fr_CA".

Please review the [Language and Locale Designations](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002144-BBCEGGFF) document.

English is international "en". "en_GB" is for English in Great Britain. It's best to create an en.lproj that contains your international English. If you choose to add GB specific spellings such as "Colour" instead of "Color", add them to en_GB.lproj.

Answer (score 1):

A nice easy list can be found on [Applingua's DevZone blog](http://applingua.com/devzone/2011/06/using-the-correct-language-codes-en-ja-fr-de-etc/):